# HTTP Client says - ClientOSError: [Errno 104]

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, асинхронность

Всем привет! Использую Aiogram 3, все работало как надо, и вдруг возникла такая ошибка - HTTP Client says - ClientOSError: [Errno 104].

По тому, что я вычитал в интернете, я понял, что ошибка может быть связана с этим фрагментом кода:

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')
                user_id = str(callback.from_user.id)
                scheduler.add_job(bot_msg.extrapass_free_spin, trigger='interval', hours=3, kwargs={'user_id': user_id})
                scheduler.add_job(bot_msg.noextrapass_free_spin, trigger='interval', hours=4, kwargs={'user_id': user_id})
                scheduler.add_job(bot_msg.arena_updater_no_extrapass, trigger='interval', hours=2, kwargs={'user_id': user_id})
                scheduler.add_job(bot_msg.arena_updater_extrapass, trigger='interval', hours=1, kwargs={'user_id': user_id})
                scheduler.add_job(bot_msg.set_extrapass_inactive, 'interval', minutes=10, kwargs={'user_id': user_id})
                scheduler.add_job(bot_msg.clanwar_updater, 'interval', minutes=10, kwargs={'user_id': user_id})
                scheduler.start()
```

а точнее с тем, что эти задачи выполняются асинхронно и одновременно у большого кол-ва пользователей. Пожалуйста, подскажите что делать? Может я вообще ни в ту сторону воюю?